Problem with nvidia-driver
I have ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. Recently when I turned my laptop on, it suddenly got stuck with a blackscreen. Figuring it was a graphic driver issue, i enter in with nomodeset, and tried to purge and reinstall Nvidia-driver. Now I cannot install it, nvidia-smi is giving me failed. I cannot sudo modprobe, since I have secure boot on. But if I disable secure boot, my computer get stuck in blackscreen again. Anyone has this issue before? Please help
Basically the only way i escape the black screen is booting with Secure Boot and nomodeset.

Hit ESC once as the BIOS/UEFI texts show up at boot; that should make the grub menu appear, select "advanced options" and then "recovery mode", new menu: fsck, network and root prompt options; hit Enter one extra time - and you are now at a bash prompt as root user. dpkg -l | grep -E ^ii.*nvidia displays any remnant nvidia driver packages, Do apt purge on them, then do dpkg -l | grep nvidia and select some other driver (server versions only if it is a server version of ubuntu!) to apt install - and as it is done, reboot to try again...

Does this answer your question? How do I know which NVIDIA driver I need?

Hi @stumblebee, I reinstall ubuntu 20.04 and it still have this problem. Nvidia-driver still not installed and has to nomodeset to boot. Also no longer require secure boot to boot

@Hannu i did all of that before reinstallying ubuntu. Still didnt work
